# Direct replies in Teams should show preference to people already involved in the discussion

Tags: feature-request, comments, stack-overflow-for-teams

There are currently eight people on my team who have names that start with "Ro". Only one of them is interacting with the question in any way but he's the sixth person in the drop down list.

When you're used to only having the choice of the few people who have commented on or written the post, two letters is usually sufficient to autocomplete their name. With the new ping system (which I do generally really love, by the way), you could have many possible matches for names depending on how common the name is.

Can you please make it possible for the system to list choices to prioritize (in no particular order):

1. the OP of the post you're commenting on.
2. the OP of the question if you're commenting on one of the answers.
3. the other commenters who have participated in the post.
4. others involved in the post (editors, people who were notified).

It's much more likely that I'm going to want to ping one of these people than everyone else in the Team who hasn't interacted with the post.

Right now, I can't even tell *what* order they're in! It's certainly not alphabetical.

Comment: Clearly the best solution is to [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) user names according to how likely a person is to be pinged. (We also have this problem on our internal Team only with `Jo`.)

Comment: Y'all are way too preferential to people with J names. I'm tempted to change my name to "Joan" just to have a better chance at a job.

Comment: Why do you want to ping the OP of a post/question. He gets notified automatically, at least on regular SO. I bet the same goes for Teams.

Comment: I don't think the OP of a question gets notified about comments on answers to their question, @Luuklag.

Comment: @Luuklag Sometimes, to keep who you're talking to clear, it's good to add a direct reply, regardless of if they'd be notified already. The system actually allows for this. If there's no comments, pinging the op doesn't show their username but once there's a few, it does. And, having the username autocomplete is useful for people with weird names.